# Spring Scheduler with shedLock stop triggering next calls after sometime

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

I have below piece of code to trigger a sync at given frequency, current frequency was 1 hour.

```
@SchedulerLock(name = "userSync", lockAtMostFor = 180_000L)
@Scheduled(cron = "${user.sync.cron.expression}")
public void scheduledSync() {
    logger.info("starting user sync...")
    performSync();
    logger.info("user sync completed!")
}
```

This piece of code was running fine for many days. Suddenly, the sync was stuck after start (only the sync start logger printed) and no longer firing the subsequent calls.

How to fix the scheduler in order to work if one attempt failed?

Comment: What does performSync() do?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli call a LDAP and retrieve user data and update in in DB.

Comment: Because if you say that "starting user sync" is printed then it must be stuck in this mehtod

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes, it is. my question is how to recover from such scenario?

Comment: That depends on what this method does and where in this method it is stuck

Comment: @SimonMartinelli it was stuck at LDAP lookup.

Comment: Then is your problem solved?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli No. I don't want to solve the issue in LDAP, which is not in my control. Simply I want my scheduler to recover from such a scenario and keep firing next subsequent calls.

Comment: How should this work? You thread is blocked so you have to find a way to stop accessing LDAP